# Load dataframe to oracle db using python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and was trying to do coding to understand it more.
I have an expense sheet which is not a structured one and using python I managed to extract,clean and load required data into an excel sheet.

[Data loaded in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvUe0.jpg)

I want to load the same data in oracle db instead of loading in excel file. 
I initially tried using cx_Oracle and later switched to sqlalchemy thinking that may help

'*df.to_sql('AB_EXPENSE',con,if_exists = 'append',index=False)*'

But when I execute this I see below error which looks to me like its taking the header also as values to be loaded in table

[Error while loading to db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3X6Y.jpg)

I already have table created in db with cols same as that in dataframe and all I need is to just load/append data alone from Dataframe to respective cols in db.

Data types:

[Oracle Table dtype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqPjd.jpg)

[DF dtype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR3cG.jpg)

Comment: Please check which datatypes exist in your dataframe with code `df.dtypes`. And check the types of columns in sql table via `describe AB_EXPENSE`

Comment: @Vad1m added data type screen shots in main post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inconsistent datatypes in "year" column between SQL table and pandas df. Type before uploading data:

```
df.loc[:,'YEARS']=df.loc[:,'YEARS'].astype('int')
```